Issue with Creating camp Display Upload Ad in Google Ads API v14 - python
I'm trying to create an display upload ad in Google Ads API v14, but I'm encountering issues. Specifically, I'm getting an "INVALID_ARGUMENT" error with the message "Mutates are not allowed for the requested resource."
def create_display_upload_ad_group_ad(
    client, customer_id, ad_group_id, ad_asset_resource_name
):
    """Creates a new HTML5 display upload ad and adds it to the given ad group.

    Args:
        client: An initialized Google Ads client.
        customer_id: The Google Ads customer ID.
        ad_group_id: The ID of the ad group to which the new ad will be added.
        ad_asset_resource_name: The resource name of the media bundle containing
            the HTML5 components.
    """
    # Get the AdGroupAdService client.
    ad_group_ad_service = client.get_service("AdGroupAdService")

    # Create an AdGroupAdOperation.
    ad_group_ad_operation = client.get_type("AdGroupAdOperation")

    # Configure the ad group ad fields.
    ad_group_ad = ad_group_ad_operation.create
    ad_group_ad.status = client.enums.AdGroupAdStatusEnum.PAUSED
    ad_group_ad.ad_group = client.get_service("AdGroupService").ad_group_path(
        customer_id, ad_group_id
    )

    # Configured the ad as a display upload ad.
    display_upload_ad = ad_group_ad.ad
    display_upload_ad.name = "Ad for HTML5"
    display_upload_ad.final_urls.append("http://example.com/html5")
    # Exactly one of the ad_data "oneof" fields must be included to specify the
    # ad type. See: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/latest/Ad for
    # the full list of available types. By setting a "display_upload_ad"
    # subfield it sets that as the "oneof" field for the Ad.
    display_upload_ad.display_upload_ad.media_bundle.asset = (
        ad_asset_resource_name
    )
    display_upload_ad.display_upload_ad.display_upload_product_type = (
        client.enums.DisplayUploadProductTypeEnum.HTML5_UPLOAD_AD
    )

    # Add the ad group ad to the client account and display the resulting
    # ad's resource name.
    mutate_ad_group_ads_response = ad_group_ad_service.mutate_ad_group_ads(
        customer_id=customer_id, operations=[ad_group_ad_operation]
    )
    print(
        "Created new ad group ad with resource name "
        f"'{mutate_ad_group_ads_response.results[0].resource_name}'."
    )

Error Message:
Request with ID "xKDxTq8R83Lu7ElSsLBwYw" failed with status "INVALID_ARGUMENT" and includes the following errors:
Error with message "Mutates are not allowed for the requested resource.".
        On field: operations
        On field: create
        On field: ad

file was uploaded and returned the path Uploaded file with resource name 'customers/12344/assets/12234' and I entered it in the function's ad_asset_resource_name
i try to v14
Despite these checks, I'm still encountering the same error. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

I found the answer
Copy this paragraph and put it into gpt 4.0
To create a responsive display ad, you need to populate the following required fields of ResponsiveDisplayAdInfo:
marketing_images
square_marketing_images
headlines. headlines
long_headline
descriptions
business name
